# How can I build voip app on react native?

Tags: react-native, webrtc, voip, phone-call

I want to build voice/video react native app. I read a lot of stuff but I am confused. There are webrtc, twillio, callkit, but amongst of them the best is webrtc as I read and can you advise me what is the best way to build VoIP app on react native?

Answer (score 3):

First we have to understand that a VoIP server can use different protocols for signaling like SIP.

To build a webrtc app and communicate with a Voip server you have to implement some protocol that uses the server.

You can use the library [SIP.js](https://sipjs.com) or [JsSIP](https://jssip.net) to implement the functionality of a softphone.

If you want a more advanced softphone you can modify demos like [Sipml5](https://www.doubango.org/sipml5/)